no such table error on laravel fresh installation
i'm getting this error on a fresh Laravel installation and I don't know where the error is  coming from or where it is attempting to run this query from.
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: sessions (Connection: sqlite, SQL: select * from "sessions" where "id" = nP0nQ4xISlb3C8o6KVpl86TUj7QplAi8G0QNw624 limit 1)


it seems your env SESSION_DRIVER is set to database. change it to SESSION_DRIVER=file and the error will be resolved.

OMG you did it! This was it!  Thanks, I've been stuck for 2 days on this but how could anyone who is just starting out with Laravel ever know this? is a there documentation that says this is what one must do?

check out the doc here

Don't delete the create_users_table migration if you don't have users but have sessions (with database driver) in your app. The migration file 0001_01_01_000000_create_users_table.php contains Schema::create('sessions', function (Blueprint $table). Not the most expressive, elegant syntax :-(.

Laravel using database to manage sessions by default. you have to create your database first.
if you installed a fresh Laravel app, run this command:
php artisan migrate

or you can rebuild database if it exists:
php artisan migrate:fresh

